# Very slow single pandas apply/groupby call

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a small dataframe (200 * 19).  I want to apply a function to each row.  There's no sub-loops.  I've tried using groupby and row apply:

```
# using groupby
def get_experimentError(df, otherParam):
    dfr = df.groupby('round')
    tmp = lambda df0: get_trialError(df0, otherParam)
    trialError = dfr.apply(tmp)
    return trialError

# using row apply
def get_experimentError(df, otherParam):
    tmp = lambda df0: get_trialError(df0, otherParam)
    trialError = df.apply(tmp, axis=1)
    return trialError


# function called
def get_trialError(trialdata, otherParam):
    # condition on obs
    posterior = get_posterior(trialdata['xObs'], trialdata['yObs'], otherParam)

    # get point with lowest expected value
    hat = exploit(posterior['mu'])

    # get error
    xerr = abs(hat['x'] - trialdata['drillX'])

    return xerr
```

Everything called in get_trialError is fully cythonized and fast.  In both cases, the timing is dominated by pandas' single reduce call, or each groupby call:

```
# Profile for call using row apply:
Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1   10.320   10.320   10.394   10.394 {pandas.lib.reduce}
  200    0.013    0.000    0.019    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:1225(svd)
  400    0.008    0.000    0.013    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py:9(linspace)
  200    0.006    0.000    0.031    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:1519(pinv)
  403    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
  800    0.004    0.000    0.019    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:500(__getitem__)
  400    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.arange}
  200    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py:190(eye)
  800    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {method 'get_value' of 'pandas.index.IndexEngine' objects}
 1000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
 1600    0.002    0.000    0.007    0.000 {pandas.lib.values_from_object}
  800    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py:3424(get_values)
  800    0.002    0.000    0.012    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py:1387(get_value)


# Profile for call using groupby
Ordered by: internal time                                                                                                                                                   [277/1926]
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      201   10.336    0.051   10.472    0.052 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py:652(f)
      201    0.013    0.000    0.019    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:1225(svd)
      402    0.008    0.000    0.014    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py:9(linspace)
      805    0.006    0.000    0.022    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py:2827(iget)
      201    0.006    0.000    0.031    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py:1519(pinv)
      410    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        1    0.004    0.004   10.479   10.479 {pandas.lib.apply_frame_axis0}
    11002    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 {isinstance}
      413    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.arange}
      805    0.003    0.000    0.059    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1053(_get_item_cache)
      810    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:87(__init__)
      807    0.003    0.000    0.005    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py:3286(__init__)
      804    0.003    0.000    0.014    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1490(__getitem__)
      201    0.003    0.000    0.004    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py:190(eye)
      807    0.003    0.000    0.009    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:114(__init__)
      805    0.003    0.000    0.032    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py:2799(get)
      806    0.003    0.000    0.065    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:1720(__getitem__)
      804    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 /Users/jsb/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1544(_convert_key)
```

It's sorted by tottime, so unless there's something weird about pandas interaction with cProfile, This shouldn't fold in time to do the actual analyses.  What can I do to speed this thing up?

Comment: What does your `get_trialError` function return?

Comment: get_trialError returns a single float.  Going to edit now...

Comment: I can't think of anything offhand that would cause it to be this bad (10 seconds to reduce a 200-row DataFrame).  Do you have a self-contained example with sample data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Data's sensitive, so I can't post.  xObs and yObs are both small (>10elts) float vectors, drillX and drillY are floats, and nothing else is really being passed around.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't see the use of the groupby version.  If you want to apply a function to *every* row, groupby doesn't make sense.

Comment: was just using it for clarity/possible future abstraction.  at the time, each row is it's own round, so each group is a df with one row.  This might not always be the case, so the row apply would only be a temporary fix (but it's not faster, anyway, so I guess not)